# Echo only info - Session PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session, printing, echo

How can I only echo the information in a session that people added by them self? My script:

```
<?php
session_start();

$array = $_SESSION["wenslijst"];

if (isset($_POST["item"]) && (int)$_POST["item"] > 0)
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION["wenslijst"]))
        {
            $_SESSION["wenslijst"] = array();
            $_SESSION["aantal"] = array();
        }

        $i = 0 ;
        while ($i < count($_SESSION["wenslijst"]) && $_SESSION["wenslijst"][$i] != $_POST["item"]) $i++;
        if ($i < count($_SESSION["wenslijst"]))
        {
            $_SESSION["aantal"][$i]++;
        }
        else 
        {
            $_SESSION["wenslijst"][] = $_POST["item"];
            $_SESSION["aantal"][] = 1;
        }
}

?>
```

When I add a product my array looks like this, I only echo the bold message: (see the long code as my spefic number for a product)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [**f805862bbd430d0673f3f949249326f3**] => 
        )
)

Thanks all for your help.

Aantal means: count

Wenslijst means: wishlist

Comment: I want echo them all. When people added a new product, there are more numbers.

Comment: use a for loop? or print_r();

Comment: "Wenslijst (Dutch)" means wishlist  "aantal (Dutch)" means number or amount... side note try not mixing in Dutch terms with english when programming it's a very bad habit of Dutch PHP programmers...

Comment: May be $_SESSION["aantal"][$i]++; should be             $_SESSION["aantal"][$i++]; ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in this part of coding. Print_r, what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do i understand you correctly, that your array looks like this?!

```
[0] => array(
    "your_super_long_product_key" => array(),
    "another_super_long_product_key" => array(),
    "awesome_super_long_product_key" => array(),
)
```

So you could access the data like this:

```
foreach(array_keys($array[0]) as $key) {
    echo $key . "\n";
}
```

This will give you:

```
your_super_long_product_key
another_super_long_product_key
awesome_super_long_product_key
```

To loop through your whole array like this use:

```
foreach($array as $dataset) {
    foreach(array_keys($dataset) as $key) {
        echo $key . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: My array look likes this: 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [f805862bbd430d0673f3f949249326f3] => ) [1] => Array ( [0615debdf23301012fb5b070f07c9fa5] => ) )

Comment: Ow, sorry. I didn't see your latest code. Thanks mate this worked for me!

Comment: @Henio: Please consider marking this answer as the correct one if the timer is up. Thx :)